# How can i save the user selected option after refresh

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm using a `mat-option` and the default value is `10` but the user can change this number from the option list, how can i save his variable if he select let's say `25` and even after he refresh the page the default value is his choice.

I've tried `localstorage` but the value resets after refreshing the page

```
<div class="col-md-auto">
                <mat-form-field style="width: 100px;">

                <mat-label>Elements on page</mat-label>
                <mat-select style="width: 100px" [(ngModel)]="limit">
              
                  <mat-option value="10">10</mat-option>
                  <mat-option value="25">25</mat-option>
                  <mat-option value="50">50</mat-option>
                  <mat-option value="100">100</mat-option>
                  
                </mat-select>
               
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
```

and my typescript is like this

```
limit:any = '10';

ngOnInit(): void {
    localStorage.setItem("limit", localStorage.getItem("limit"))
  
  }
```

Comment: You are saving the data in `localStorage` but it doesn't look like you are retrieving the data anywhere when the page reloads.

Comment: What you are doing now is setting the value inside the localStorage when the page is loaded. Or I think you want to set the current localStorageValue inside your 'limit' parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want when the page is loaded is set the localStorage value inside your limit parameter :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.limit = localStorage.getItem("limit");
}
```

Then, you must catch when user change value to set it inside the localstorage :

```
changed(): void {
    localStorage.setItem("limit", this.limit)
  }
```

And update your HTML :

```
<mat-select (change)="changed()" style="width: 100px" [(ngModel)]="limit">
             
                  <mat-option value="10">10</mat-option>
                  <mat-option value="25">25</mat-option>
                  <mat-option value="50">50</mat-option>
                  <mat-option value="100">100</mat-option>
                  
                </mat-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how the `<mat-option>` stuff works, so I'll just take a guess.  Basically you need to save the data whenever that option is changed. On `ngOnInit` you need to get the data, if any, and us that value instead of the default.

```
limit: number = 10;

ngOnInit(): void {
  const storageLimit = localStorage.getItem("limit");
  this.limit = storageLimit ? +storageLimit : this.limit;
}

onChangeSelection(selectedValue): void {
  localStorage.setItem("limit", selectedValue);
}
```

note that I've set this up to use `limit` as a number now instead of a number inside of a string which used the `any` type before.

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is by creating a `Service` as below and inject the same in your `Controller`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
  private storageName: string = "MyStorage";

  constructor() { }

  setSettings(data: any) {
    localStorage.setItem(this.storageName, JSON.stringify(data));
  }

  getUserSettings() {
    let data = localStorage.getItem(this.storageName);
    return JSON.parse(data);
  }

  clearUserSettings() {
    localStorage.removeItem(this.storageName);
  }

  cleanAll() {
    localStorage.clear()
  }

}
```

**UPDATE**

In case you do not want to use `localStorage` you can opt for a [cookie service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service) as well. You can save the desired `object` into a `cookie` that never expires and then try to read it from there before making your request next time they reload the page.

Hope that helps.